# Pyspark regexp_replace and replace it with captured group

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark table like this.

```
|col                                   |
|a function createdf and function roll |
|ground function power                 |
```

I am trying to capture the pattern `function <word>` and create a new column.
My expected output will be

```
|col                                   | new_col
|a function createdf and function roll | [function createdf, function roll]
|ground function power                 | [function power]
```

Code I tried:

```
pat_function_definition = '((function)\s+(\w+))'
df.withColumn('temp', f.split(f.regexp_replace("col", "(((function)\s+(\w+)))" , "$1"), ",")).show()
```

Spark version is 2.4.

Answer (score 1):

For Spark 3.1+, you can use [`regexp_extract_all`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#regexp_extract_all) function with a lookbehinds regex `(?<=\bfunction\s)(\w+)`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([("a function createdf and function roll",), ("ground function power",)], ["col"])

df.withColumn(
    "new_col",
    F.expr(r"regexp_extract_all(col, '(?<=\\bfunction\\s)(\\w+)')")
).show(truncate=False)

#+-------------------------------------+----------------+
#|col                                  |new_col         |
#+-------------------------------------+----------------+
#|a function createdf and function roll|[createdf, roll]|
#|ground function power                |[power]         |
#+-------------------------------------+----------------+
```

---

For older versions, you can replace all words that are not preceded by the word `function` by a comma `,` then split the resulting string and remove empty values:

```
df.withColumn(
    "new_col",
    F.split(F.regexp_replace("col", r"(?<!\bfunction\s)\b\w+", ","), ",")
).withColumn(
    "new_col",
    F.expr("filter(new_col, x -> trim(x) != '')")
).show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Hi @blackbishop, I am using spark 2.4, kindly suggest in 2.4 please

Comment: actually my data contains some junks as well , like ([", "], (, ){, . so my output is showoing like this... imgur.com/a/LWGs393 :(